# Why is writing to Bigquery using Dataflow EXTREMELY slow?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I can stream inserts directly into BigQuery at a speed of about 10,000 inserts per second but when I try to insert using Dataflow the 'ToBqRow' step (given below) is EXTREMELY slow. **Barely 50 rows per 10 minutes** and this is with **4 Workers**. Any idea why? Here's the relevant code:

```
PCollection<Status> statuses = p
        .apply("GetTweets", PubsubIO.readStrings().fromTopic(topic))
        .apply("ExtractData", ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, Status>() {
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(DoFn<String, Status>.ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
            String rowJson = c.element();

            try {
                TweetsWriter.LOGGER.debug("ROWJSON = " + rowJson);
                Status status = TwitterObjectFactory.createStatus(rowJson);
                if (status == null) {
                    TweetsWriter.LOGGER.error("Status is null");
                } else {
                    TweetsWriter.LOGGER.debug("Status value: " + status.getText());
                }
                c.output(status);
                TweetsWriter.LOGGER.debug("Status: " + status.getId());
            } catch (Exception var4) {
                TweetsWriter.LOGGER.error("Status creation from JSON failed: " + var4.getMessage());
            }

    }
}));

statuses
        .apply("ToBQRow", ParDo.of(new DoFn<Status, TableRow>() {
            @ProcessElement
            public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
                TableRow row = new TableRow();
                Status status = c.element();
                row.set("Id", status.getId());
                row.set("Text", status.getText());
                row.set("RetweetCount", status.getRetweetCount());
                row.set("FavoriteCount", status.getFavoriteCount());
                row.set("Language", status.getLang());
                row.set("ReceivedAt", (Object)null);
                row.set("UserId", status.getUser().getId());
                row.set("CountryCode", status.getPlace().getCountryCode());
                row.set("Country", status.getPlace().getCountry());
                c.output(row);
        }
    }))
        .apply("WriteTableRows", BigQueryIO.writeTableRows().to(tweetsTable)
                .withSchema(schema)
                .withMethod(Method.STREAMING_INSERTS)
                .withWriteDisposition(WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
                .withCreateDisposition(CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED));

p.run();
```

Comment: Do you perform any computationally-heavy operations on your `statuses`? Maybe you've fallen into Beam graph fusion optimization (https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc#fusion-optimization) and your multiple transforms are squashed into single transform which might cause bottleneck. Try doing reshuffle before `ToBQRow`.

Comment: I have updated code above. As you can see, I don't do any computationally heavy operations. Just read a message from a PubSub topic, extract relevant info, create a TableRow object & write it. The 'ToBQRow' is the real culprit it seems: Input Collections -> Elements added -> 13,829. Output Collections -> Elements Added -> 249.

Comment: I don't see any kind of windowing, that might be an issue

Comment: Don't understand why I've to use a Window! I am not aggregating dataI In any case, tried this but it didn't help: (Not sure if this is correct usage!):

                .apply("GetTweets", PubsubIO.readStrings().fromTopic(topic))
                .apply("TimeWindow", Window.into(SlidingWindows.of(averagingInterval).every(averagingInterval)))

Comment: Have you tried reshuffling?

Comment: A few questions
1.Which logging api are you using? log4j or slfj?
2.Is it possible for you to remove the unnecessary logging you are doing for each status and rerun the job? Assuming you are using log4j, it does a lot of string construction and merging which incurs a computational cost. Also if you are logging everything, you are pushing all your data to stack driver so you are adding more IO and network bound operations unnecessarily on your df job.
3.could you tell me more about the Status object you are using? What is the complexity for setting and getting? Maybe use a hashmap instead?

Comment: Comparing against code that does work (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/training-data-analyst/blob/master/courses/streaming/process/sandiego/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/training/dataanalyst/sandiego/CurrentConditions.java) I don't see anything usual in your code snippet above.  I don't have Method.STREAMING_INSERTS, so perhaps you can try removing it.  Also, try replacing the BigQueryIO with a count operation or TextIO and see how many tweets pass your filter.  Perhaps you are getting only 50 tweets in 10 minutes?

Comment: @HarisNadeem I am using slf4j. Status object is very lightweight. Here's Javadoc for it (http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/Status.html). Removed logging completely but that didn't help.

Comment: @Lak - Yes I started from CurrentConditions. I think you meant "don't see anything unusual", correct? Removed STREAMING_INSERTS. That's didn't help. No, I am sure tweets are coming in at a higher speed. As mentioned above, I see this for the "ToBQRow" step: Input Collections -> Elements added -> 13,829. Output Collections -> Elements Added -> 249. That means, 13,829 tweets have come in but only 249 have been written to BigQuery -:(

Comment: @MarcinZablocki- I haven't tried 'reshuffling'. I am new to Dataflow. Can you please suggest where & how I should add 'reshuffling' to the code given above?

Comment: I've read the docs for Status without much success on understanding what happens underneath BUT I think the issue is with the ***TableRow*** object. Can you validate that TableRow is not being populated with Null data? Second, can you validate that the schema is matching with the TableRow? If they are not, that would explain why only partial rows are being mapped since the schema only matches with certain rows (i.e. when the extras are null). If you can validate that those are not the issues, I'll try to keep digging

Comment: @HarisNadeem - Your suggestion regarding **NULL** helped me figure out what the issue was. Actually, BigQuery allows us to set NULL values for columns. That wasn't the issue. Problem was, status.getPlace() was returning NULL & so it was probably throwing NullPointerException that I was **not able to see in the logs.** It is working very fast now. Thanks a LOT.

Comment: I had a feeling there was something wrong in that portion of the code. And glad to have helped ^_^ 
This is the first time I get to update a partial answer lol ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out **Bigquery under Dataflow is NOT slow.** Problem was, 'status.getPlace().getCountryCode()' was returning NULL so it was throwing NullPointerException that I couldn't see anywhere in the log! Clearly, Dataflow logging needs to improve. It's running really well now. As soon as message comes in the topic, **almost instantaneously** it gets written to BigQuery!

Comment: I'm also experiencing slow writes. How did you find out about the error if it was not in the logs?